# why to make the hasOwnProperty() test in loops

Tags: javascript

Sorry , this can be a silly question but i wonder why i often see such as test in some for/foreach loops.

```
for (var item in data) {
     if (data.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
```

As item indeed belongs to data (its an element of it) so what is the utility of making the test with the hasOwnProperty() method?

Comment: To check if the property is of the object itself and not inherited from prototype

Comment: You could have removed the `if (data.hasOwnProperty(item)) {` to see the changes, then you **must** have understood why to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To weed out properties that are from the object's prototype (or its prototype's prototype, etc.).

Example:

```js
// A prototype object
var p = {
  prop1: "proto prop"
};

// Create an object using that as its prototype
var o = Object.create(p);

// Give it a property
o.prop2 = "obj prop";

var key;

snippet.log("All of o's enumerable properties:");
for (name in o) {
  snippet.log(name); // We'll see prop2 and prop1
}

snippet.log("Only o's *own* enumerable properties:");
for (name in o) {
  if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    snippet.log(name); // We'll see prop2, and *not* prop1
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```